# Crop the exact center of a canvas image source

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have made an input form that receives uploaded files into a canvas element. Because different images come with different sizes, the uploaded image is always stretched to fit my canvas size which is `400` * `350`.

How do I crop the exact center of the uploaded image to the ratio of my canvas size, so as to fit the the uploaded image into the canvas.

```
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
<canvas id="up_canvas" width="400" height="350" style="border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>

<script>
//get input as canvas
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

var canvas_one  = el("up_canvas");
var context_one = canvas_one.getContext("2d");

function readImage() {
if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
       var img = new Image();
       img.onload = function() {
         context_one.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 350);
       };
       img.src = e.target.result;
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
}
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

To draw specific part of the image, you must provide additional parameters in the `drawImage()` function. If you call it with 9 arguments, it is `void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);`, where `s` stands for source, and you specify which part of the provided image you want to draw.

We always crop rectangle with size 400x350, but we have to calculate the `sx` and `sy` attributes. In your case, you want to draw image like this:

```
context_one.drawImage(img, 
                      (img.width - 400) / 2,   // sx, 200 pixels to the left from center
                      (img.height - 350) / 2,  // sy, 175 pixels above center
                      400, 350, 0, 0, 400, 350);  // sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh
```

If you are providing smaller images too, the sx and sy parameters would be negative. You can take care of that case like this:

```
context_one.drawImage(img, 
                      Math.max(0, (img.width - 400) / 2),
                      Math.max(0, (img.height - 350) / 2), 
                      400, 350, 0, 0, 400, 350);  // sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh
```